# How can I change background color on text element?

Tags: javascript, velo

I am attempting to use Wix's javascript to set the background color of a text element based on the value of that element.

Here's my code:

```
$w.onReady(function() {
  // Write your JavaScript here
  let textVal = $w('#text36').text

  if (textVal === "Available" || null) {
    $w('#text36').html = `<h1 style="background-color: green">${$w("#text36").text}</h1>`

  } else {
    $w('#text36').html = `<h1 style="background-color: red">${$w("#text36").text}</h1>`

  }
```

It is always "Red" and never green no matter the value of the text36 element. If I manually set the value of text36 it works so the issue is getting the value. This is coming from a CMS Field.

Comment: Do you need to trim the text? i.e. `if (textVal.trim() === "Available") {`

Comment: Tried it and didn't work

Comment: is it a text element inside a repeater item? in such case you'll need to use the onItemReady function.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you should move your test code inside the onReady function of your dynamic dataset, in order to be sure that all data has been loaded before testing the text value:

```
$w.onReady(function() {
    // Write your JavaScript here

    $w('#dynamicDataset1').onReady(() => {
        let textVal = $w('#text36').text

        if (textVal === "Available" || null) {
            $w('#text36').html = `<h1 style="background-color: green">${$w("#text36").text}</h1>`
        } else {
            $w('#text36').html = `<h1 style="background-color: red">${$w("#text36").text}</h1>`
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: here's the updated code...$w.onReady(function() {
    // Write your JavaScript here

    $w('#dynamicDataset').onReady(() => {
        let textVal = $w('#text36').text

        if (textVal === "Available") {
            $w('#text36').html = `<h1 style="background-color: green">${$w("#text36").text}</h1>`
        } else {
            $w('#text36').html = `<h1 style="background-color: red">${$w("#text36").text}</h1>`
        }
    })
}--it's flagging this bracket tho